# spinner selected item to open new array list using database android

Tags: java, android, database, android-spinner

I have display multiple row in the `RecyclerView` and top of the one filter select the filter open the `Spinner` and select the `Spinner` item to open only selected list how to show 

**i m new in android programming**

**My class**

```
private List<People> peolesListAll = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private AlertAllCustomeAdapter alertAllCustomAdapter;
private DataBaseHelper db;
Spinner spinner;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alertlist_all);

    BuildData();

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinnerData();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    alertAllCustomAdapter = new AlertAllCustomeAdapter(this, peolesListAll);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(alertAllCustomAdapter);
    alertAllCustomAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, alertAllCustomAdapter.getItemCount());

    private void spinnerData() {
    db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // lables.set(0, "ALL");
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

}
private List<People> BuildData() {
    db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    if (db.open()) {
        peolesListAll = db.getAllPeople();

    }
    return peolesListAll;
}

 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `onItemSelected` method you can retrieve the selected filter with `position` parameter from your spinner data (here the List lables). Then, re-populate your recylcer adadpter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the view like this :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String filter = (String) spinner.getAdapter().getItem(position);
    // update your peolesListAll according to the selected filter (with loop or anything else)
    alertAllCustomAdapter.setData(peolesListAll) // write setData(List<People> data)
    alertAllCustomAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: any example@Francois L.